# Put an icon in input[type=text] to the RIGHT of the current text, possible?

Tags: css, input

I need an `input[type=text]` field with these rules:

`input[type=text]` - no border, the user see the current entered text

`input[type=text]:focus` - the user will see an input box + border on all the input field.

So far, easy task.

Now for the last but impossible task:

`input[type=text]:hover` - same as normal BUT show an edit icon to the RIGHT of the current entered text and NOT to the right of the input control.

I never managed to think about a way to do it, any ideas?
The problem is that there's no way in css to control the text inside the input field. Maybe to have both a normal text and input field and to play with show/hide in js?

Comment: I guess you would need JavaScript to read the current text content, “clone” it into some different element that has the same formatting applied, so that you can determine its actual width in pixels - and then position a background image accordingly. Or you try the approach outlined in https://css-tricks.com/text-input-expanding-bottom-border/ (if you can work with `contenteditable` instead of an actual input element.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but I managed to get something working as a proof of concept, please note that this is using FontAwesome for the icon.

https://codepen.io/martincarlin87/pen/GaQmxe

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="test">
    <span>edit <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keydown', handleInput);

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', handleInput);

function handleInput(e) {
  if (document.getElementById('test').value != '') {
    let caretPosition = e.target.selectionStart;
    let newCaretPosition = ((caretPosition * 10) + 1) + 15;
    console.log('Caret at: ', caretPosition);
    document.querySelector('div > span').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.querySelector('div > span').style.left = `${newCaretPosition}px`;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('div > span').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('div > span').style.left = `15px`;
  }
}
```

the left position calculation needs a bit of work, it might be easier to simply use the length of the value instead of the caret position.

At first I tried a pseudo element but those can't be added to inputs, hence the div container, but then it turns out you can't easily modify their styles using JavaScript either, so went with a span element instead.